# Using paramiko tring to connect RHEL6.5 vm giving "Servname not supported for ai_socktype" error message

Tags: redhat, python-2.6, paramiko

I new in python, I am try to connect `RHEL vm` by `key authentication`.I have two `RHEL6.5 vm1,vm2` and `Python 2.6.6` on both.

First I generate keys on vm1 and copy to vm2 as using below cmd.

On vm1 execute below cmd:

```
1) ssh-keygen -t rsa
2) After key generation 
3) ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/id_rsa.pub root@vm2
```

After that I am able to login that vm2 from vm1

```
ssh -i  /root/.ssh/id_rsa root@vm2
```

manually this is working fine but i am doing it programmatically by using python, below is my code: run from vm1

**SSHKey.py**

```
import paramiko

sshcon   = paramiko.SSHClient()
sshcon.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
connection = sshcon.connect('vm2', 'root','/root/.ssh/id_rsa')
print "-----------------"
print connection


**OutPut:**

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SSHKey.py", line 5, in <module>
    connection = sshcon.connect('vm2', 'root')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 277, in connect
    socket.getaddrinfo(hostname, port):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -8] Servname not supported for ai_socktype
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think RHEL6.5 vm1 not able to communicate with RHEL6.5 vm2.Python version looks good you need to install paramiko on RHEL6.5 vm2.Run below cmd.

1) yum list python-paramiko --showduplicates
This will give you available package 
2) yum install python-paramiko
This will install paramiko on your rhel vm.